# Why are there no $16$ by $32$ Hadamard circulant matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, number-theory

Two rows of a matrix are *orthogonal* if their inner product equals zero. Call a matrix with all rows pairwise orthogonal an *orthogonal matrix*. A [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) is one where each row vector is rotated one element to the right relative to the preceding row vector.  We will only consider matrices whose entries are either $-1$ or $1$.

For number of columns $n= 4,8,12,16,20,24,28, 36$ there exist $n/2$ by $n$ orthogonal circulant matrices.

> Why are there no circulant matrices with $16$ rows and $32$ columns which are orthogonal?

Or to phrase it differently, is it possible to prove they don't exist without enumerating them all?

**Example 6 by 12 matrix**

\begin{pmatrix}
  -1 &\phantom{-}1 &\phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 &\phantom{-}1 & -1 &\phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1\\
  -1 & -1 &\phantom{-}1 &\phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 &\phantom{-}1 & -1 &\phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & -1\\
  -1 & -1 & -1 &\phantom{-}1 &\phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 &\phantom{-}1 & -1 &\phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1\\
  -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 &\phantom{-}1 &\phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 &\phantom{-}1 & -1 &\phantom{-}1 & -1\\
  -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 &\phantom{-}1 &\phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 &\phantom{-}1 & -1 &\phantom{-}1\\
  \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 &\phantom{-}1 &\phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 &\phantom{-}1 & -1\\\end{pmatrix}

Comment: If we add $n = 2$ to the list, would you say that it is exhaustive, or are those just the numbers that you know work?

Comment: @Arthur Those are just the numbers that I know work.  $n=2$ is the only one that is not a multiple of $4$ that could work however. For $n>4$ we know $n$ has to be a multiple of $4$.  I don't know anything else however.

Comment: And you have reason to believe that $n = 32$ doesn't work because you've run a computer program or something?

Comment: @Arthur That is exactly right.

Comment: @dorothy What does the 6 by 12 matrix look like? I am trying to improve my intuition because I would have guessed that the number of columns must be at least 2 to the power of 1 less than the number of rows.

Comment: @Justpassingby I just added an example.

Comment: All rows in the matrix are determined by the last row because it's circulant.  The orthogonality conditions then gives you contraints in the 32 variables. How many equations arise from the pairwise orthognaility requirement? My guess is that the system is over determined resulting in no solution.

Comment: @dorothy Thanks, I was somehow fixated on rows with an equal number of positive and negative entries!

Comment: @user55622 One point is that as the matrix is circulant, we need only compare orthogonality to the first (or last) row.

Comment: I don't quite follow. If a row is orthogonal to the first, you're not guaranteed it's orthogonal to the second, are you?

Comment: @user55622 The dot product of two rows $i$ and $j$ in a circulant matrix is determined by $abs(i-j)$. For example, if row1 . row2 = 0 then row4 . row5 = 0. This is because the pairs of elements for the dot product are the same, just rotated.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. Are you familiar with the Hadamard circulant conjecture?

Comment: @user55622 Yes I am. However I have no idea if this has any relation to a conjecture about $n/2$ by $n$ Hadamard partial circulant matrices. I would love to know if it does.

Comment: If the Hadamard circulant conjecture is true then we can never extend our $n/2$ by $n$ matrices downward even a single row (because then orthogonality would follow for the complete cycle of $n$ rows)

Comment: @Justpassingby This is true! But, it doesn't say anything at all about the existence of $n/2$ by $n$ Hadamard partial circulant matrices, right?  I find it surprising that there is nothing said about $n/2$ by $n$ Hadamard partial circulant matrices in the literature, at least that I can find.

Comment: @dorothy Not directly, no. Cannot vouch for the literature but I believe you. The geometric picture is always the same, though: how many mutually orthogonal diagonals does the $n$-cube have?

Comment: @dorothy Have you figure out, though, how many constraint equations you actually have. It's a combinatorial problem.

Comment: @user55622 I haven't managed to work that out sadly.

Comment: @Justpassingby A very interesting related question is simply if there exist an infinite number of $n/2$ by $n$ Hadamard partial circulant matrices.

Comment: @user55622 For $n=2m$ after eliminating the obvious redundancies the constraints are $m-1$ homogeneous quadratic equations in $2m$ variables so at least in the sense of dimensionality the system is not overdetermined.

Comment: @dorothy If $A$ is an $m\times m$ circulant Hadamard matrix then it easy to show that the $m$ by $2m$ matrix $$\left ( A\>  A \right )$$ is also circulant Hadamard. If a $16\times 16$ circulant Hadamard matrix existed, then so does a $16\times 32$ matrix. However, Turyn in his paper "Character sums and difference sets" showed that there are no circulant Hadamard matrices of order $8p$. This doesn't completely answer your question but at least shows your negative answer is consistent with known results.

Comment: @user55622 Thank you that is interesting. However, we also suspect there are no $n$ by $n$ circulant Hadamard matrices at all for $n> 4$ of course so I am not sure how far this gets us given that there are plenty of $n/2$ by $n$ ones for $n>4$ (and also for $n= 8p$).

Comment: @Dorothy My idea is to relate the $16\times 32$ case back to a square circulant Hadamard matrix known not to exist. I don't see how to do that at the moment. By the way, do your matrices of size $n/2$ by $n$ have a more specific name?

Comment: @user55622 That sounds like a good idea but I am not sure how you are going to make this work for $16$ by $32$ but not $8$ by $16$ for example. I don't know a name for this sort of matrix sadly. I find it hard to believe this sort of matrix has never been considered before but I have found no mention so far in the literature (although I am no expert).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These matrices are known as circulant partial Hadamard matrices and a good reference for these, along with recent results, is $\textit{Circulant partial Hadamard matrices}$ by Craigen, Faucher, Low, and Wares, Lin. Alg. Appl. 439.

Denote by $r\mbox{-}H(k\times n)$ a $k\times n$ circulant Hadamard matrix in which a row (and hence all) has sum $r$. The authors compile a table of the maximum values of $k$ for $n\le 64$ and all values of $r$. You can see that the $16\times 32$ matrix doesn't exist along with the $22\times 44$ matrix.

One of the first results in the paper is that if $r\mbox{-}H(k\times n)$ exists then $n$ is divisible by 4. This is why your column numbers are all multiples of 4. Another result is that if Ryser's conjecture is true then $k\le \frac{n}{2}$. The authors show also that there is empirical evidence that the maximum value of $k=\frac{n}{2}$ is attained almost always for $r=2$. A conjecture of Delsarte, Goethals, and Seidel is that a $2\mbox{-}H(k\times 2k)$ exists if and only if $k-1$ is an odd prime power. These two results combined would explain why the $16\times 32$ and $22\times 44$ cases don't exist. It also indicates that the next non-existent case could be $34\times 68$.

Comment: Thank you for this. If I understand you correctly, it is not yet known if there exists an infinite number of $n/2$ by $n$ partial circulant matrices, for example, but Delsarte, Goethals, and Seidel conjecture that there do.

Comment: Oh and there is also this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/227600/are-there-infinite-constructions-for-partial-circulant-hadamard-matrices for you to copy this answer to as well :)

Comment: @dorothy The question of whether there are an infinite number of $\frac{n}{2}$ by $n$  partial circulant Hadamard matrices is different to explaining why some don't exist.I would expect an infinite number to exist based on the conjecture because you can always find a $k$ such that $k-1$ is an odd prime power. However, the result maybe known; I'll try and find it.

Comment: @dorothy It is known that an infinite number of $n/2$ by $n$ circulant partial Hadamard matrices exist. This is Theorem 9 in the above mentioned paper. It states that for every prime power $p$, there exists a $2\mbox{-}H((p+1)\times 2(p+1))$.

Comment: Thank you for finding this!  It does seem that there exist $n/2$ by $n$ circulant partial Hadamard matrices for $ n = 4,8,12,16,20,24,28,36,44,48,52,56,60,64$.  You wrote that the next non-existent case could be $33$ by $66$ but $66$  is not a multiple of $4$. Was that a typo?

Comment: I don't have access to the paper that proves Theorem 9. Do you know if there is an explicit construction of these matrices?

Comment: @dorothy You're quite correct, I should have said $38\times 76$. This is only a candidate because you're not guaranteed the maximum occurs for $r=2$. Concerning your second question, Theorem 9 uses a result from another paper. I will take a look at it to see if it's constructive.

Comment: @dorothy I believe it is possible to construct these matrices. Someone just posted this question and I provided an answer. Here's a [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1617517/55622).

Comment: Thank you. Ultimately I would like to write computer code to actually construct these matrices so the more explicit the better :)

Comment: Lembik just made the same request. I told him that I'll need a little time to study the papers. I did a literature search to see if someone else had done this but no luck.

Comment: @dorothy Do you know how to write code to compute the Legendre symbol for Galois fields?

Comment: @dorothy I emailed Robert Craigen, one of the authors of the paper I cite above. He says that it should be possible to write an algorithm to compute a sequence of these matrices and is willing to help. I suggested that you contact him directly since this is outside my field. Can you give me some of your particulars, by way of introduction? If you don't want them posted on SE then I can give you my email address.

Comment: Thank you! I have mentioned this to my colleague whose real interest this is who may contact Robert Craigen directly. My interest was just out of mathematical curiosity.