# Explicit construction of $n/2$ by $n$ circulant partial Hadamard matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

In [Circulant partial Hadamard matrices](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379513005533) by Craigen, Faucher, Low, and Wares it is stated in Theorem 9 that there is a $(p+1)$ by $2(p+1)$ circulant partial Hadamard matrix for every prime power $p$. This is very interesting but I would really like an explicit construction and I can't work out if or where one is given.

> Is there an explicit construction that gives a $(p+1)$ by $2(p+1)$
>   circulant partial Hadamard matrix for prime power $p$?

Answer (score 3):

The result you quote is true because negacyclic $C$-matrices of order $p+1$ exist. In *On orthogonal matrices*, J. Math. and Phys. 12 (1933), Paley gave a construction of $C$-matrices using the Legendre symbol $\chi$ of the Galois field GF$(p)$. A variation of this construction leads to a negacyclic form for these Paley matrices. The reference for these results is Delsarte, Goethals, and Seidel, *Orthogonal matrices with zero diagonal. II*, Can. J. Math., Vol. XXIII, No. 5 (1971).

Comment: Thank you for the references. Would you be able to explain in your answer how you do the construction explicitly?

Comment: @Lembik I'll need a little time to study the paper by Delsarte et al. It's rather involved and explicit calculations are not given. It seems though that a general construction can be done.